# Printing on java/kotlin on Mac

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to use Java to print a document. But I don't have a printer and for this I wanted to print a pdf file. On Windows it turns out without problems, but on Mac errors appear. I ask for help. How to do it right?

Error:

**java[19682:512872] allowedContentsTypes : UTType pdf does not have a valid preferredFilenameExtension and will be ignored when validating the file name**

[image]

**Printing failed because PMSessionBeginCGDocumentNoDialog() returned -30872.**

```
val printable = object : Printable{
    override fun print(graphics: Graphics?, pageFormat: PageFormat?, pageIndex: Int): Int {
        if (pageIndex>0){
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE
        }


    return PAGE_EXISTS
    }
}
val printer = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob()
printer.setPrintable(printable)

if (printer.printDialog())
    printer.print()
```

Comment: @Sweeper What should I add if I need to print to pdf?

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe I put the question incorrectly. When launching the printer selection window, I need to select Save as PDF. The image is attached to the question

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed that sentence. I can now reproduce the first error "UTType pdf does not have a valid preferredFilenameExtension...". However, I still cannot reproduce the second error, and I _was_ able to save the pdf file successfully.

Comment: @Sweeper When I click on save as, a dialog box appears later, where it says "To print this file, you need to configure the printer." And the Apple menu -> System Preferences-> instructions, etc.

Comment: I am on macOS 12.1 and this works on Java 14 and Java 17. What is your macOS version and Java version?

Comment: @Sweeper macOs = 12.1. java = 17